# Is there a way to use std::get(std::tuple) with a non-const int as template argument?

Tags: c++, for-loop, templates, tuples, constexpr

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the members of an `std::tuple`, but it seems that I can only ever use `constexpr ints` or `const ints` in the `std::get` template argument. I've looked around and I saw some solutions or ideas using recursive functions or structs, but I don't really understand them. I'd very much appreciate help with this (my code is below).

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, int> tuple(3, 4);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        std::cout << std::get<i>(tuple) << std::endl;
}
```

And here is the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:31: error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression
         std::cout << std::get<i>(tuple) << std::endl;
                               ^
```

Comment: Interestingly, the answers for C++11 and C++14 are different here. I assume C++14 is fine?

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, C++14 is fine.

Comment: Template parameters are always `constexpr`. C++ does not work in any other way. So the short answer to the specific question is "no, there is no way". However, "how to iterate over a tuple" is a completely different question.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Thanks. How would I iterate over the tuple, then?

Comment: If there's only two as per you example, I *wouldn't* loop over them, I'd just use constants `0` and `1` to print them independently.

Comment: @paxdiablo True, but I was looking for a solution that would work for any sized tuple with any types of members.

Comment: @Rahul: "*How would I iterate over the tuple, then?*" That is a completely different question. [There are many such questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%2B%2B%5D+tuple+iterate).

Comment: No probs, Rahul, that's why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer :-)

Comment: Yes you can only use const ints inside std::get for vectors.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use std::get(std::tuple) with a non-const int as template argument?

No, there isn't. Template arguments are always compile time constants.

Besides, return types are also set in stone at compile time, and given that tuple elements can be of different types, the compiler couldn't know what type to return which would be a problem.

Now, even though you cannot have `std::get` with a runtime parameter, there are ways to iterate the elements. `std::apply` from the standard library will call a provided function with the tuple elements as arguments. You can use a variadic template arguments to accept any tuple, and expand the arguments with a fold expression.

```
auto visitor = [](auto&&... args) {
    ((std::cout << args << '\n'), ...);
};
std::apply(visitor, tuple);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the compiler doesn't know which index is going to be accessed, it can't (in general) know which type to return from the tuple. So the trick is to not return anything. Usually, to use a helper function that uses a switch statement to decide which type to use, and pass the function to that.

I don't have a compiler handy, but that would look something vaguely like this:

```
 template<class Func, class... Args>
 auto apply_indexed(Func&& func, std::tuple<Args...>& tuple, int index) 
 -> decltype(func(std::get<0>(tuple)))
 {
     switch(index) {
     case 0: return func(std::get<0>(tuple);
     case 1: return func(std::get<1>(tuple);
     }
     throw std::invalid_argument("illegal index to invoke_tuple " + std::to_string(index));
 }
 
int main() {
    std::tuple<int, int> tuple(3, 4);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        apply_indexed([](auto& element){
            std::cout << element << std::endl;
        }, tuple, index);
}
```

This creates an anonymous lambda that can accept *any* of the tuple types, and then uses a switch statement to decide which element to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that `std::get` expects a compile time value whereas your variable `i` is only known at run time. You can do this:

```
std::tuple<int, int> tuple(3, 4);
std::cout << std::get<0>(tuple) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::get<1>(tuple) << std::endl;
```

but it will only work for a two-element tuple. However, there is a way using a variadic template function that will allow to use a tuple of any size. You will need an index list to get elements within a tuple. In C++14 onward you've got [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), which can be created using `std::index_sequence_for`. `std::integer_sequence` represents a compile-time sequence of integers, and when used as an argument to a function template the parameter pack of type `std::size_t` can be deduced and used in pack expansion.

This will do want to want in C++14 onwards:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void print_tuple_impl(Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using unused = int[];
    //print each tuple element using index sequence
    (void)unused { 0, ((std::cout << std::get<Is>(t) << std::endl), 0) ... };
}

template<typename... Args>
void print_tuple(std::tuple<Args...> tup)
{
    //create index sequence and pass to print_tuple_impl
    print_tuple_impl(tup, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, int> tuple(3, 4);
    print_tuple(tuple);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jK9on5).

---

In C++17, you can use a fold expression without creating a temporary array for pack expansion:

```
((std::cout << std::get<Is>(t) << std::endl), ...);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/evYaq8)